# Ubuntu Server VIRTUALBOX - GRUB error

Tags: server, grub2, virtualbox

I using Ubuntu Server 15.10/amd64 and when installation on VirtualBox begins to end I see message "failed to install GRUB record". And when I tried run system without GRUB it showed up black screen. How to correctly install Ubuntu Server or GRUB record?